# Displaying, editing and validating different data than writing to / reading from the model using Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, architecture

## My setup

I have a `value` coming from the db as a `number`. This value should *always be a number except for the purpose of displaying it in an `input`-element and validating the input*. Only in those cases the number has to *be a `HEX` value*.

Here is what should happen:

1. `value: 200` is coming from the service.
2. `?value=200` is being used in the router as a parameter.
3. `value: 'c8'` is displayed in the `input[type=text]` in the view.
4. the user changes this value to `fa`
5. ths validator should (if possible) validate `fa` to check if it is a *valid HEX expression*.
6. if it is, then `value = hex2Number('fa')` should lead to `value: 250` in the model, **while `fa` should still be in the `input`-element to edit.**
7. `value: 250` should afterwarts be used in the router again and should be going back to the server.

The exact same usecase applies for e.g. minutes:seconds being edited and seconds being saved in the db.

**I don't** need help with the `hex2Number()`-method ;-)

## My question(s)

1. is this possible using **Reactive Forms**?
2. ... or do I have to switch to Template Driven Forms instead?
3. is there a best-practice for having different data in the GUI and the model behind it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, it is possible. Create a custom `ControlValueAccessor` for that.

2) It is compatible with both Reactive and Template driven forms.

3) `ControlValueAccessor` is the best practice.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast reply! I remember stumbling across this one day without further investigation. Now seems to be the time! If everything works out I'll come back and rate this answer!